# Condition the loop in Tensorflow on placeholder inputs

Tags: python, loops, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to use loop in Tensorflow for certain calculation. The issue is that as long as a constant/variable is used in the condition (`i less than var` in the code below), the code works fine. But if I use the condition on loop against a placeholder variable, the code fails to initialize with error of 'non-initialized placeholder'.

```
self.batch_size = batch_size = config.batch_size #batch_size = 5, for example    

self._sequence_length = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [batch_size], name='sequence_length_placeholder')

def condfunc(i, var, sum, seq):
            return tf.less(i, var)

def bodyfunc(i, var, sum, seq):
            return [tf.add(i, 1), var, tf.add(sum, tf.gather(seq, i)), seq]

i = tf.constant(0)
sum = tf.constant(0)
#var = tf.Variable(tf.gather(tf.shape(self._sequence_length), 0))    #Error on conditioning on placeholder tensor
var = tf.Variable(batch_size)
_, _, sum, seq = tf.while_loop(condfunc, bodyfunc, [i, var, sum, self._sequence_length])
```

> So, how can we condition the loop in Tensorflow on dynamic input (placeholders)?

Remark: The code snippet below has no significance in terms of use-case but is provided to highlight the issue faced. The actual use case can be accumulating the logits of only the actual sequence rather than complete sequence in RNN network, or summing up the cost of only actual sequence, or Viterbi inference of tags of only actual sequence rather than complete padded sequence.

Comment: Usually when you use a batch size you have more dimensions, like: `[batch_size, output_size]`. `tf.add(i,1)` returns a tensor, you might want to use `tf.assign_add(i,1)`.

why don't you use the funcitons `reduce_*` for your case? It seems what you are looking for